# How to load second partialview after success inserted in first partialview?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a view named `Register.cshtml` and 2 partialview named `_AddUser.cshtml` And `_UserList.cshtml`.

When I run the project shows `register.cshtml` and `_AddUser.cshtml` load in view. I want to load `_UserList partialview` after success inserted in `_AddUser partialview`.

DefaultController:

```
 public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    UserRepository UR = new UserRepository();
    Automation_DBEntities database = new Automation_DBEntities();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(Users user, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        UserRepository blUser = new UserRepository();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ///////////////////SaveImage
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (user.UserImage != "no-photo.jpg")
                {
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/image/UserImage/" + user.UserImage)))
                        System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("/image/UserImage/" + user.UserImage));
                }
                user.UserImage = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/image/UserImage/" + user.UserImage));
            }
            user.RegisterDate = DateTime.Now;
            if (blUser.Add(user))
            {
                return PartialView("_UserList");//Inserted
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddUser()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AddUser.cshtml");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UserList()
    {
        IQueryable<AutomationSystem.Models.DomainModel.Users> list = UR.Select();
        return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_UserList.cshtml", list);
    }
```

Comment: Do not keep deleting your [previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541308/how-to-load-second-partialview-after-success-inserted-in-first-partialview) and then re-asking them!

Comment: but i cant do it by previous answers. and anyone dont other answers :-(

Comment: You need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics

Comment: add the code of register.cshtml, you can  solve your problem by using ajax, read about `Ajax.BeginForm` and `Ajax.ActionLink`